# jQuery calling post URL

Tags: php, jquery

```
   $.post('controller/method', $("#form").serialize , function(data) {
       //alert data
   });
```

It works if domain name is www.domain.com
It doesn't work if domain name is domain.com/category/

What should I do here? Or I must use PHP to help me? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you mean `.serialize()`? Also, try leaving the `www.` in there.

Comment: www.controller/method? serialize doesn't matter here.

Comment: No, I mean `www.example.com` instead of `example.com`.

Comment: @Blender: So, I should redirect example.com to www.example.com with htaccess?

Comment: Add `www.` if you know it is always going to be needed. Otherwise you are trying to do calls across subdomains which you cannot do in Ajax too easily.

Comment: @hey: One or the other. `www.` is considered a subdomain and might not work with AJAX requests.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts: I just added that you need to be consistent. You need either *no* `www.` in either of the pages or `www.` in *both*.

Comment: @Blender Yes, sorry - I deleted my comment. I totally misread yours - I thought it was directed at me. Time to sleep I think.

Comment: Lol, it's fine. OP's username might've been a bit confusing as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to support both domains, try switching to JSONP instead of a traditional ajax call.  This will work with multiple domains, but it is limited to GET requests.  So, if your php code will work with the parameters passed in the URL, this should be fine.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'controller/method',
  data: $("#form").serialize(),
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
       //alert(data);
   }
});
```

In addition to the fact that the PHP code will have to work with GET requests, it will also have to respond with JSON.  Also, that JSON will have to be wrapped in call to invoke the `$callback` function, like so:

```
<%= echo %callback . '(' . $jsonResponse . ')' %>
```

See more about JSONP here:  http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/